# How to change the field type from dropdown list to a lookup field in Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I have a requirement to change a Flow related field type from an existing Banner field(a picklist value) a dropdown list to lookup field in Flow. Is it possible to change,

Please do reply the steps to change if possible.

Thanks & Regards,
Bhuvan

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to have a true lookup field (with a magnifying glass icon) in Flow, unfortunately this is not possible right now. We are probably getting it in the future, but we do not have the ability yet. Currently, we can only use Dynamic Choices to make dropdowns, or ask for data entered into text boxes, which you can use a Record Lookup to find.